# Why did the Fidelius Charm on the Potters' house break?

Tags: harry-potter, fidelius-charm

When Harry and Hermione visit Godric's Hollow, Harry wonders something I find rather silly:

> ... they passed more cottages: any one of them might have been the one in which James and Lily had once lived...He was not  even sure whether he would be able to see the cottage at all; he did not know what happened when the subjects of a Fidelius Charm died.

Harry was a living subject of the charm, and arguably the *primary* one.  As such, the charm still should be in effect And if anyone at all could see the house it would be him.  Then they actually find the house:

> He could see it; the Fidelius Charm must have died with James and Lily.

I think that's a poor conclusion for the aforementioned reasons. But Hermione could see it, along with the wizards who put up and signed the sign.  The secret-keeper was still alive, so the secret didn't leak out via secondary keepers.

So why did the charm break?

Comment: Is there any evidence that Harry *was* one of the subjects of the Fidelius Charm? There's not a lot of information on the actual casting of the spell in the books, but if it involved some magic on the part of the subjects then it's likely Harry wouldn't have been one.

Comment: It would make sense for Harry to see it, perhaps, since he was a resident of the house and therefore would have known its location (even as a baby) - what is curious is that any magical person could see it (as evidenced by the signatures etc on the fencepost or sign or whatever it was).

Comment: It stands to reason that *"unless, of course, the Secret-Keeper chooses to divulge it"* means not only that the Secret-Keeper can tell the secret to a chosen few people, but also that he can choose to divulge the secret to all and sundry, i.e. he can *break the spell*. Remember that *Wormtail*, not the Potters, was the Secret-Keeper. So the explanation (as far as the Potter's house is concerned) is simple: Wormtail broke the spell.

Comment: The Fidelius Charm doesn't make the house invisible.  It only makes people think that the house is not the Potters' home (unless the Secret-Keeper willingly informs them).

Comment: `subjects of a Fidelius Charm` might be the "owners" of the house here. Harry definitely wasn't the owner when Fidelius Charm was put in action.

Comment: Could it be that it never broke at all? When the secret keeper dies everyone who knows where the place is becomes a new secret keeper, so since Harry lived there as a baby he is a secret keeper himself. I would maybe even argue that children of secret keepers can also see the house by default.

Answer (score 30):

**TL;DR** In canon the Fidelius Charm is inconsistently presented. It smacks of *deus ex machina* and seems to be clumsily applied mainly to smooth out or facilitate plot points that need some assistance getting from point A to point B. There is not a satisfactory answer as to why the charm broke in the way that it did because Fidelius does not have defined parameters. **ETA:** Regarding your comment to **Pureferret**, it doesn't make sense that the charm broke while Harry was still alive. It's a *great* question. It's just that there is no authoritative canon-based answer and the supplemental information provided by J.K. Rowling doesn't explain it either. There is absolutely no canon evidence that Wormtail "undid" the charm prior to Voldemort killing the Potters. Hence my concerns with the workings of the Fidelius Charm in general.

The long version:

Response to both your question and [mine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18791/precisely-how-does-the-fidelius-charm-work) on the Fidelius Charm show how confusing canon is surrounding this issue. Since I asked about Fidelius, I've done a lot of digging and reading and have concluded Fidelius is probably somewhat of a *deus ex machina*. When canon isn't clear and J.K. Rowling provides what is supposed to be clarifying information to be considered alongside what she's written in canon, it's truly difficult to suss it out. :) Here are some examples of what's been said about the Fidelius Charm:

> ‘An immensely complex spell,’ [Flitwick] said squeakily, ‘involving the magical concealment of a secret inside a single, living soul. The information is hidden inside the chosen person, or Secret-Keeper, and is henceforth impossible to find – unless, of course, the Secret- Keeper chooses to divulge it. As long as the Secret-Keeper refused to speak, You-Know-Who could search the village where Lily and James were staying for years and never find them, not even if he had his nose pressed against their sitting-room window!’
> <sub>*Prisoner of Azkaban* - pages 152-153 - Bloomsbury - chapter 10, *The Marauder's Map*</sub>

This is the first canon description of the Fidelius Charm, so this is what we have to go by off the bat.

> ‘Here,’ Moody muttered, thrusting a piece of parchment towards Harry’s Disillusioned hand and holding his lit wand close to it, so as to illuminate the writing. ‘Read quickly and memorise.’
> Harry looked down at the piece of paper. The narrow handwriting was vaguely familiar. It said:
> *The Headquarters of the Order of the Phoenix may be found at number twelve, Grimmauld Place, London*.
> <sub>*Order of the Phoenix* - page 57 - Bloomsbury - chapter 3, *The Advance Guard*</sub>

Here we are shown how a Secret-Keeper can share the secret with others, by telling them directly. So far we can assume that a secret can be divulged verbally (Peter Pettigrew, we assume) and through writing. As well, appropriately, Harry cannot see No. Twelve Grimmauld Place until well after he's read Dumbledore's message. (I do have an overall point)

> They were often joined by other Order members for dinner now, because The Burrow had replaced number twelve, Grimmauld Place as the Headquarters.
> Mr Weasley had explained that after the death of Dumbledore, their Secret Keeper, each of the people to whom Dumbledore had confided Grimmauld Place’s location had become a Secret Keeper in turn.
> ‘And as there are around twenty of us, that greatly dilutes the power of the Fidelius Charm. Twenty times as many opportunities for the Death Eaters to get the secret out of somebody. We can’t expect it to hold much longer.’
> <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 79 - Bloomsbury - chapter 6, *The Ghoul in Pyjamas*</sub>

Now we learn that the Fidelius Charm may be complex, but it's not as stable as some spells. It dilutes as a new person is told the secret and becomes weaker. Okay. It's also noted that the headquarters for the Order of the Phoenix have relocated from Grimmauld to the Burrow. There's no indication of whether or not the Burrow was placed under the Fidelius Charm as well. (Personally, I think headquartering the Order's headquarters at the Burrow would be far more obvious to the Death Eaters than Grimmauld Place, and even more dangerous. Although, I suppose, to be fair, Kreacher did rat out the Order to Narcissa Malfoy in *Order of the Phoenix*)

> Regarding Yaxley in *Deathly Hallows*:
> ‘Harry, I think he can. I – I forced him to let go with a Revulsion Jinx, but I’d already taken him inside the Fidelius Charm’s protection. Since Dumbledore died, we’re Secret Keepers, so I’ve given him the secret, haven’t I?’
> <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 223 - Bloomsbury - chapter 14, *The Thief*</sub>

Wait. *WHAT*? Now an outsider can learn a Fidelius secret by *osmosis*, just by having accidental contact with whatever is being protected by Fidelius? According to Flitwick's description of Fidelius in *Prisoner of Azkaban*, a secret must be specifically divulged to another person, and the two examples we saw of divulging a secret previously were through writing or verbally. So Yaxley just *knew*, even though nothing was explained to him? As well, Mr. Weasley had informed Harry that the Order's headquarters had been moved to a new location. There is no explanation as to why the trio couldn't have immediately stunned Yaxley and tossed him right out of No. Twelve Grimmauld Place because the Fidelius Charm originally protecting Grimmauld *specifically* involved the address for the headquarters of the Order of the Phoenix. It wasn't *Oh, and by the way, Harry Potter is hiding out here at number twelve Grimmauld Place*. By the time Yaxley hit the hearth, Grimmauld *was not* headquarters anymore. So exactly what secret was divulged? And how?

> ‘I’ve been getting them all out of The Burrow,’ he explained. ‘Moved them to Muriel’s. The Death Eaters know Ron’s with you now, they’re bound to target the family – don’t apologise,’ he added, at the sight of Harry’s expression. ‘It was always a matter of time, Dad’s been saying so for months. We’re the biggest blood traitor family there is.’
> ‘How are they protected?’ asked Harry.
> ‘Fidelius Charm. Dad’s Secret Keeper. And we’ve done it on this cottage too; I’m Secret Keeper here.
> <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 390 - Bloomsbury - chapter 24, *The Wandmaker*</sub>

So Shell Cottage was under the Fidelius Charm at the moment Dobby Apparated the trio out from Malfoy Manor. How is it possible that Harry could see it, see it's lights, and see people moving about inside *before* Bill Weasley told Harry about the charm and that he (Bill) was the Secret Keeper for Shell Cottage? (Bill also rather blithely tells Harry that a group of Weasleys -- which might include Ginny -- was under the protection of Fidelius at Auntie Muriel's. For the Weasleys' continued protection, it would have been wiser for Bill not to tell Harry this information. There wasn't a pressing need for Harry to know where the Weasleys were at that moment in time.).

Here is what J.K. Rowling has to say about Fidelius:

> **What happens to a secret when the Secret-Keeper dies?**
> I was surprised that this question won, because it is not the one that I’d have voted for… but hey, if this is what you want to know, this is what you want to know!
> When a Secret-Keeper dies, their secret dies with them, or, to put it another way, the status of their secret will remain as it was at the moment of their death. Everybody in whom they confided will continue to know the hidden information, but nobody else.
> Just in case you have forgotten exactly how the Fidelius Charm works, it is “an immensely complex spell involving the magical concealment of a secret inside a single, living soul. The information is hidden inside the chosen person, or Secret-Keeper, and is henceforth impossible to find — unless, of course, the Secret-Keeper chooses to divulge it” (*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*)
> In other words, a secret (eg, the location of a family in hiding, like the Potters) is enchanted so that it is protected by a single Keeper (in our example, Peter Pettigrew, a.k.a. Wormtail). Thenceforth nobody else – not even the subjects of the secret themselves – can divulge the secret. Even if one of the Potters had been captured, force fed Veritaserum or placed under the Imperius Curse, they would not have been able to give away the whereabouts of the other two. The only people who ever knew their precise location were those whom Wormtail had told directly, but none of them would have been able to pass on the information.¹
> [J.K. Rowling](https://web.archive.org/web/20120204062053/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_poll.cfm)

So how could Yaxley have known even a smidgen of information regarding Grimmauld Place?

See how muddy the water is?

This is a really, really long post to demonstrate why I think the answer to your question is that it's unclear why the charm broke. The information surrounding Fidelius is inconsistent and appears to be infinite, meaning there aren't fixed parameters around the magic involved. Fidelius just seems to keep morphing and changing as canon goes along.

¹<sub>This was on J.K. Rowling's website for years, but she's taken down all her Potter information in order to put it up on Pottermore. Link courtesy of the Wayback Machine</sub>

Comment: "It dilutes as a new person is told the secret and becomes weaker." Not quite. While the secret keeper is alive, only s/he can reveal it (see your JKR quote); only after s/he dies is it weakened by more people being able to give it away.

Comment: "Now an outsider can learn a Fidelius secret by osmosis, just by having accidental contact with whatever is being protected by Fidelius?" It was being brought into 'contact,' as you put it, by a secret keeper that gave him the secret. (Interestingly, JKR's quote seems to directly contradict the passing on of secret-keeper-ness at death, which is explicitly described and happens in the books)

Comment: "So Shell Cottage was under the Fidelius Charm at the moment Dobby Apparated the trio out from Malfoy Manor."  As I understand this quote, they set up the protections at Shell Cottage and Muriel's after (and because of) Harry et. al.'s arrival.  This one also seems to indicate that anyone inside a house while Fidelius is put over it retains the secret, a question which has been posed without resolution before.

Comment: It looks like most of this argument is based around `so I’ve given him the secret, haven’t I?` being truth.  However, they were in a panic at the moment and the "haven't I?" gives the intonation of being unsure.  I wouldn't take this line as gospel.

Comment: @Kevin - 1) the more people who know the secret the higher the risk for vulnerability. It's not like only a couple of people died in *Harry Potter*. 2) I understand the text. I just don't buy it. 3) I read the relevant passages before answering -- if I missed where it says in the text that the Fidelius Charm was put in place specifically for Harry, please point it out to me and I'll by all means re-evaluate.

Comment: @Izkata -- I definitely don't take it at face value because it makes no sense to me, and I cannot find an acceptable explanation that I would consider authoritative. But the book as it's written *did* take Hermione's explanation as gospel, and it took it and ran with it. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess A very late comment here: the trio took Hermione’s explanation/guess and ran with it, yes—but unless I'm misremembering, there is no evidence in the book that she was right. They stay away from Grimmauld Place just in case, but we don't hear anything about any Death Eaters ever getting in there, do we? It could be that her theory was just plain wrong, but they never found out because they didn't dare risk it.

Comment: On the other hand, if we assume that Hermione _was_ right, it would make sense that forcibly bringing someone inside the area concealed by the Fidelius charm would count as revealing the secret. If you don't know where I live, I can tell you by word, I can write the address down for you, but I can also just take your hand and lead you through the door. Once you were in, you'd be able to walk out and see where you were. That's essentially what Hermione did: she took Yaxley's hand and led him through the perimeter into the actual Headquarters.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: And furthermore, Harry is not in the first lot that Dobby saved. It is entirely consistent to assume that Dobby brought the first lot to where he knew Bill's cottage would be, and Bill saw him and revealed the secret to him, and hence on the second trip Dobby could apparate straight inside the bounds of the Fidelius charm, so revealing the secret to Harry too.

Comment: I don't think the dilution thing means the spell is *unstable* - Arthur explained what he meant in the very next sentence, and it has nothing to do with the spell decaying over time.

Comment: @user21820 No he couldn't have revealed the secret to Harry, even just by leading him inside, since he wasn't secret keeper... Even if the theory that you can reveal the secret by leading someone in is correct (and it makes a lot of sense imo), it still only is applicable to the/a secret keeper. That part just won't ever make sense except if the charm was added after Harry's arrival at the cottage.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I completely agree that divulging the location can absolutely be done by just showing someone to the door, and it would work since Hermione was a secret keeper for grimmaud Place. The interesting question that would arise is what would happen then if someone that is not the/a secret keeper attemps to take someone inside by side along apparition ? Would they bounce of the fidelius ? Would you just leave your "passenger" behind ? (related to Yaxley taking other death eaters with him later)

Comment: @Cartolin: So I mis-remembered; Harry was the one who apparated, not Dobby.

Comment: Is there any way that it could be explained with characters being wrong in what they say about Fidelius? Are there actual **events** that contradict each other?

Comment: @FabianRöling Yes, Harry knowing where Shell Cottage completely contradicts how Harry came to know about Grimmauld Place (and about everything else that is said about the Fidelius Charm). Only Bill could have divulged the secret to Harry (since he was the only Secret Keeper) yet Harry and Bill don’t communicate before meeting _at Shell Cottage_.

Comment: The Yaxley point gets even worse when you think about it. You could cut out the Fidelius part and still have The Trio conclude that Grimmauld Place is no longer safe. By bringing him there, he now knows that it's being used and can have **Snape** bring reinforcements. The scene works perfectly fine without giving Yaxley the secret.

Answer (score 12):

It appears that the Fidelius Charm can be broken by the Secret Keeper. From Deathly Hallows ch 17 "Bathilda's Secret," when Harry is reliving Voldemort's memory of going to kill the Potters: "...and now his destination was in sight at last, the Fidelius Charm broken, though they did not know it yet..." This indicates that the Charm itself had already been broken prior to the Potter's deaths and the backfire of the curse on Harry, implying the Secret Keeper (Pettigrew) had broken it.

Comment: Interesting point that it may have been broken beforehand, depending on how precise the wording is intended to be.

Comment: This would certainly make sense of a _lot_ of things.

Comment: The charm was broken for Voldemort because Peter Pettigrew ratted out James and Lily to him. Simply like when Harry read that the headquarters to the Ootp is at 13 Grimmauld Place, then he could see the house. So the charm was not in effect for him any more.

Comment: Also, even if we consider the charm broke for everyone, how come everyone in the wizarding world knew to go and look in Godric's Hollow for the Potters? They were in hiding.

Answer (score 5):

I was under the impression, purely from my reading of the books, that all the charm did was made a secret, and anything related <strike>unknowable</strike> undiscoverable, so long as the secret keeper kept the secret. *In fact, quoting the harry potter wikia*

> *The Fidelius Charm is a complex and powerful Charm that takes a specific piece of information (a secret) and implants it into a being's **soul**.*

As such, if the secret was *the residence of the Potters* or *the location of the Potters* the fact that they have died means they no longer have a location or residence. *There is no longer a secret.*

Furthermore, the secret keeper, the real subject of the charm, let the secret loose. If breaking the charm required death, all that would be required was to kill everyone close to the Potters. It's much harder to subtly extract the secret, and thus more secure.

*Again quoting HP Wikia:*

> *Whilst one cannot force secondary Keepers to divulge the information they have learnt*, it is unknown if coercive methods to have the primary Keeper reveal the location (such as Veritaserum or the Imperius Curse) would work.

It appears that once the primary secret keeper dies the others that know of the information become secondary secret keepers (i.e, when the Albus dies and the secret of Grimmauld place is no longer 'kept', Snape is now a secondary secret keeper.)

Again this is mostly from memory, and [HP-Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fidelius_Charm) so I don't know for certain.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, Harry was still alive so his residence/location, which was that house, should still have been protected. And the secret keeper didn't, as far as we know, let the secret loose so much as just tell one person.

Comment: I think all it takes is one person else to know, and the spell doesn't care who, to break the secret. After his parents died, it was no longer his residence, he moved in with his Auntie/uncle.

Comment: Do people not think this answer as accurate?

Comment: I think it's at best incomplete. It doesn't address why the charm would break *while Harry survived*. But if you could present evidence that Wormtail undid the charm entirely instead of just telling Voldemort, that would answer it. (Undid the charm entirely; no matter who or how many he told, if the charm was still in effect they couldn't tell others, others would need to get it straight from Peter.)

Comment: HP Wikia is the pox on answers for myself and others, I know. It's a *really* inaccurate source to cite.

Comment: It's pretty clever explanation that we should be aware of how they phrase the secret for Fidelius Charm, like in the Potters case. But then we have problem with Orden of the Phoenix secret. It is clear from Dumbledore's note that the secret was about the place of the Order's headquarters. So the secret basically should have been smth like "Order's headquarters are at Black's house". But after the house ceased to be the headquarters the Charm should have been broken, because as you said - there was no longer a secret.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should consider the secret that the Fidelius charm was protecting. From the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 10 - The Marauder's Map: (McGonnagall speaking to Flitwik, Fudge and Rosmerta):

> "James Potter told Dumbledore that Black would die rather than tell where they were, that Black was planning to go into hiding himself... "

The wording strongly suggests that the secret was the location of the Potters.

Also, we have this from Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Chapter 1 The Boy who Lived:(Hagrid speaking to Dumbledore)

> "No, sir - house was almost destroyed, but I got him out right before the Muggles started swarmin around".

From that - we know that the location that was being protected by the Fidelius charm was almost destroyed - which might have made it possible right then for the Muggles to see the house.

Now - when Harry realises that the FIdelius charm must have broken - he observes the house from outside. (Harry Potter and the Deathly Hollows - Chapter 17: Bathilda's Secret)

> The hedge had grown wild in the sixteen years since Hagrid had taken Harry from the rubble that lay scattered amongst the waist-high grass. Most of the cottage was still standing, though entirely covered in the dark ivy and snow, but the right side of the top floor had been blown apart; that, Harry was sure, was where the curse had backfired. He and Hermione stood at the gate, gazing up at the wreck of what must once have been a cottage just like those that flanked it. "I wonder why nobody's ever rebuilt it?" whispered Hermione. "Maybe you can't rebuild it?" Harry replied. "Maybe it's like the injuries from Dark Magic and you can't repair the damage?"

Although Harry assumes that the damage cannot be repaired and compares it to injuries from Dark Magic - if it were indeed true - we can confirm that the damage to the house itself was beyond repair.

So the charm wasn't broken by the death of James and Lily - nor by Wormtail revealing the secret to all the people who left their wishes (we know he could not have - since he was thought to have been killed by Sirius immediately after James and Lily's death). The charm broke because the house that it was protecting was destroyed - presumably when Voldemort's killing curse rebounded instead of killing Harry.

Answer (score 1):

### The spell was no longer in effect when Voldemort got to the house

We know from [HP and the Cursed Child](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29056083-harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child) that the spell no longer in effect  *before* Voldemort arrived at Godric's Hollow, presumably because Pettigrew *had canceled the spell entirely* rather than because he let Voldemort in on the secret.

> Scorpius Malfoy and Albus Potter use a time-turner to travel back to the 1980s, immediately *prior* to Voldemort's arrival. Both of these individuals can see the house, indicating that it's no longer protected by the Fidelius Charm.

and

> **SCORPIUS:** *And **here it is** —* 
>  
>  **ALBUS:** ***The home of James, Lily, and Harry Potter*** . . .
>  
>  A young, attractive couple leave a house with a baby in a pushchair. ALBUS moves towards them, SCORPIUS pulls him back.
>  
>  **SCORPIUS:** *They can’t see you, Albus, it might damage time, and we’re not doing that — not this time.*

Comment: I'm beginning to think that The Cursed Child should be considered an unbook.

Comment: @EvilSnack - My advice is to simply accept it. In a few months we're going to have a veritable tidal wave of "Fantastic Beasts" continuity errors to deal with. They'll make this look like nothing.

Answer (score 1):

RE: the Cursed Child

> It does seem pretty clear from the Cursed Child that whatever Pettigrew did to reveal the secret to Voldemort must have destroyed the enchantment completely, since the house is visible to Albus and Scorpius, and eventually to Harry, Ron, Hermione, Ginny and Draco.

RE: the introduction of it in Prisoner of Azkaban

To me the confusing part has always been that to switch out secret keepers meant that no one, except Sirius and Peter, knew the secret, not even Dumbledore. If Dumbledore had known, then he could have testified on Sirius' behalf. Yet Dumbledore knew what had happened in Godric's Hollow quickly enough to notify Hagrid to get Harry prior to the Muggle police showing up.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question of *why* the Fidelius Charm broke though.

Answer (score 0):

It is traditional in many fantasy universes for certain types of spells/charms to elapse/break when the caster dies. It seems that the most likely explanation is that the Fidelius Charm is such a spell and that, since the most likely caster of the charm was either James Potter or Lily Potter, that it almost certainly died with them.

Comment: Why would James be more likely to have cast the spell than Lily? Lily was quite talented in Charms and Potions, while canon suggests James was strong at DADA. The Fidelius Charm breaks when the Secret Keeper - who may or may not be the caster - dies. I'm still curious why you conclude James would have been more likely to have cast the charm than Lily? I don't recall either of the Potters being suggested as the caster of the charm in any of the books. :)

Comment: I meant to put both of them. My mistake. Actually, the Fidelius Charm does NOT break when the Secret Keeper dies. That was covered in The Deathly Hallows after Dumbledore dies. No, the caster is *not* explicitly mentioned for the Potter house, but it is a reasonable assumption that since it's their house, they cast it. This creates a plausible explanation for the spell failing.

Comment: You're right on the Fidelius breaking. At this point I'm so braindead I can't even figure out how the Fidelius breaks. I'm still unclear, though, why if one of the Potters cast the charm it explains why the spell failed. :)

Comment: It's a logic chain based on assumptions. 1) In some universes, some spells fail when the caster dies; 2) James or Lily could be the caster of the Fidelius Charm on the Potter house; Therefore, the Fidelius Charm on the Potter house MAY have failed because the caster (James or Lily) died. It's a logic chain based on supposition an EWAG, but that's the best explanation that I can come up with.

Comment: If you want to say the spell breaks when the caster dies, then why is there **any protection at all** on Grimmauld Place considering the secret keeper (Dumbledore) and the most likely caster of the spell (Sirius) are both dead

Comment: I'd rather say all normal spells - curses, jinxes etc. cast at a specific target - fail when the castor dies. This is what lets Harry Potter know that Dumbledore is dead before he falls down from the tower - the total body bind curse that Dumbledore had placed on Harry fails and Harry can now move. The exceptions to these spells might be those intangible ones without a specific target, like the curse on the DADA post, the Fidelius Charm, the Unbreakable Vow etc.

Answer (score -1):

pettigrew/wormtail may have been alive but the reason the fidilus charm broke is because pettigrew told voldemort where to find them once the secret keeper tells someone who wants to find the person for the wrong reasons the charm breaks