# Why didn't the Fidelius charm on Shell Cottage stop the heroes from apparating there from Malfoy Manor?

Tags: harry-potter, fidelius-charm

Considering Bill Weasley was the Secret Keeper for Shell Cottage, how did Harry and Dobby Apparate to the cottage? Or, for that matter, Luna and Ollivander?

Comment: I love this question -- it's something I've wondered about for years. I personally think it's an author error, but so many people hate hearing me say that :)

Comment: @Slytherincess I think it's fairly clear the (and the most consistent with everything else) that the charm was cast after the crew arrived. Is there any evidence against it?

Comment: I'm correcting myself. Arthur is Secret Keeper for the Weasley Family; Bill is Secret Keeper for Shell Cottage: *‘How are they protected?’ asked Harry. ‘Fidelius Charm. Dad’s Secret Keeper. And we’ve done it on this cottage too; I’m Secret Keeper here.* So ignore what I wrote about Arthur, but the Fidelius Charm is "an immensely complex spell" and we don't know how it's performed. I think if it had been done after Harry arrived, it would've been in the story. Also "protected" is past tense, suggesting the Fidelius Charms on the Weasleys and Shell Cottage had already been performed. My $.02. :)

Comment: I just don't see that theory as plausible. It doesn't mean I'm right, but it makes absolutely no sense *to me* (being careful here to speak only for myself). Especially seeing as we don't know how the Fidelius charm works and it's described as very complex. If I were to pick one of the choices, I'd go with number three, although I still wonder if it's a canon error. :)

Comment: Number two, that it was performed after they arrived, is completely consistent with everything else we know about the situation and charm, so there's no sense complicating it further. Occam's razor.

Comment: Why would the fidelius charm stop you from apparating in/out of somewhere? It's not an anti-apparition spell!

Comment: @Mooz I tend to agree.. although I think Bernadet's #2 answer fits the facts best (especially because Bill says he organised the removal of the family from the Burrow to Muriel's meaning they take at least some measures. I think the reason it is NOT in the story is because Harry is so blinded by grief over he doesn't register it and so we don't learn it either), the fact the cottage is fideliused would not have prevented Harry apparating to it's location, Flitwick stated: you could press your face to the window and not see the protected people (presumably as long as they are inside the place).

Comment: @Slytherincess Very late reply here, but _protected_ here is not past tense. It's a past participle, used in this case with _are_ to make a **present** passive construction. “And we've done it on this cottage too” is also present (present perfect). So both statements relate only to what the state of affairs is at the moment Bill is speaking, which doesn't preclude the Fidelius Charm being cast after Harry and Dobby appear.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There`s three theories going around for this:

1 - Ron has been made into an additional Secret-Keeper for Shell Cottage.

2 - The Fidelius charm wasn't cast until after the trio reached the cottage, since they didn`t know they were in immediate danger yet before that.

3 - Elf magic is beyond Wizard Magic so it didn`t affect Dobby.

The second theory is the most likely, but none are confirmed :)

Comment: The third is confirmed due to Dobby and Kreacher apparatting in and out of the Black home...

Comment: @izkata its confirmed as possible but not confirmed that that is the only/actual reason

Comment: And there's a [fourth theory](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22742/3500), that the Fidelius Charm is not explained well enough by J.K. Rowling, and can serve as a convenient plot facilitator in certain situations when needed by the author. I love me some J.K. Rowling, don't get me wrong, but there is *no way* that Harry and company should have been able to Apparate inside the protective enchantments of the Fidelius Charm at Shell Cottage without having been made Secret Keepers themselves. If I were to go with any of the above three theories, I would choose number three -- House-elf magic.

Comment: IMO, the actual text around there is very clear that the charm wasn't cast until after they arrived. And it makes the most sense; the family was in no danger and not hiding, so there was no reason for a Fidelius and it would have raised eyebrows if there was one.

Comment: The family was indeed in danger: *‘I’ve been getting them all out of The Burrow,’ [Bill] explained. ‘Moved them to Muriel’s. The Death Eaters know Ron’s with you now, they’re bound to target the family – don’t apologise,’ he added, at the sight of Harry’s expression. ‘It was always a matter of
time, Dad’s been saying so for months. We’re the biggest blood traitor family there is.’* And they were in hiding. Raised eyebrows? Whose eyebrows? In the middle of a huge war it would've raised eyebrows to perform a protective charm? I don't feel the book supports this position. :)

Comment: I would like to go with theory 2, after reading the passage in the book again. I think that the Weasleys went into hiding, since Ron was seen. So probably once our heroes reached Shell cottage, the spells were cast. Though I do have to agree with Slytherincess in that the  Fidelius Charm is not explained well enough. The elf magic angle is a little weak

Comment: @Izkata: Kreacher was already serving the Order when it had their headquarters, so Professor Dumbledore (the secret keeper) has probably let him on to the secret.

Comment: Definitely not #3. From my reading of the book, Ron, Hermione and Griphook apparated there together. Harry took Dobby. So, #3 can't explain how Harry was able to get in as Dobby didn't do the apparition.

Comment: Elf magic is understandable, as kreacher also could move into Grimauld place. But how could Ron speak about the place "shell cottage"?

Answer (score 11):

I think Dobby didn't Apparate into the area protectd by the charm, but a little way off, in the beach. Even the death eaters could hang around the street outside Grimauld Place yeah?

And then when Dobby and the rest Apparated, Bill and Fleur came up didn't they? And then they were told to "come up to the house" weren't they? (Correct me if im wrong:-)). So that means that the Fidelius charm was cast before Harry arrived.

Comment: Everything you're saying is correct, from my memory. It's the interpretation I took when reading the book as well. Your answer could probably use a little editing so it contains statements rather than a series of (possibly rhetorical) questions.

Comment: He wouldn't be able to see it... 
> Harry squinted around through the darkness. There seemed to be a cottage a short way away under the wide starry sky, and he thought he saw movement outside it.

Comment: *All three of them glanced back at Shell Cottage, lying dark and silent under the fading stars, then turned and began to walk toward the point, just beyond the boundary wall, where the Fidelius Charm stopped working and they would be able to Disapparate.* Implies that the entire property was under the Fidelius Charm.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a plot hole. Like the many others Rowling has. We try so hard to cover them but this one is pretty obvious. Bill is the secret keeper at Shell Cottage

> “How are they protected?” asked Harry.
>   “Fidelius Charm. Dad’s Secret-Keeper. And we’ve done it on this cottage too; I’m Secret-Keeper here.

Even if dobby apparated inside the Fidelius Charm they still wouldn't be able to see it! They would have to be told about it by Bill. The Fidelius Charm is used so many times as *deux ex machina* that it's ridiculous. When you see post after post discussing the plot holes around it, you know that there are many problems...

Comment: In my experience, crying “plot hole!” often indicates lack of thinking on the part of whoever is crying it. The [answer by penelopecharmed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/40869) nails it IMO.

Comment: He wouldn't be able to see it... Based on the answer you mention
> Harry squinted around through the darkness. There seemed to be a cottage a short way away under the wide starry sky, and he thought he saw movement outside it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because they apparated to the space **outside Shell Cottage**.

> 'Hermione?' he said suddenly. 'Where is she?'
>
> 'Ron's **taken her inside**,' said Bill, 'She'll be all right.'
>
> [...]
>
> They were all sitting in the living room when he entered the little hall, their attention focused upon Bill, who was talking. The room was light-colored, pretty, with a small fire of driftwood burning brightly in the fireplace. Harry did not want to drop mud upon the carpet, so **he stood in the doorway**, listening.

Bill placed the Fidelius Charm *on the Cottage itself*.

> “Fidelius Charm. Dad’s Secret-Keeper. **And we’ve done it on this cottage too**; I’m Secret-Keeper here."

So that didn't stop them from apparating there.

Comment: *All three of them glanced back at Shell Cottage, lying dark and silent under the fading stars, then turned and began to walk toward the point, just beyond the boundary wall, where the Fidelius Charm stopped working and they would be able to Disapparate.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that this is even a question--the third reason is clearly the best reason--Dobby is the one apparating in and out of Shell cottage, everyone else is just a tag-along.  Dobby's ability to apparate to places where wizards can't is shown repeatedly throughout the series.  The most important example is just before this, he goes to Malfoy Manor.  The Malfoy's house is protected and no one can apparate in or out, but Dobby does so easily.  He also is shown to apparate into and out of Hogwarts, where no one, not even Dumbledore (despite the 6th movie) can do so.  He does this in Book 2 and both Kreacher and Dobby apparate within Hogwarts repeatedly in Book 6--again, Wizards cannot do this, house elves can.  Also, Kreacher managed to apparate out of Voldemort's cave, which was heavily protected, and no wizard or witch would have been able to do so.  Therefore, the Fidelius Charm obviously does not apply to house elves, as this has been proven over and over again in the Harry Potter universe.  The answer is number 3, Dobby did it.

Comment: It's proven time and time again that House Elves can Apparate to locations that wizards can't, but only ever by themselves; there's no instance of a House Elf bringing along a wizard when they Apparate to a location protected by anti-Apparition defences. It makes sense that it's simply not possible otherwise the defences would be pretty meaningless, as anybody with a House Elf would be able to bypass them trivially.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - keep in mind that most of wizardkind seem to see house elves as little more than servants; Voldemort himself, despite his great wisdom, neglects this fact when he takes Kreacher to the cave. I think it's quite possible that house elves could breach the defenses of anti-Apparition; it's just that so few humans want to see themselves indebted to (or otherwise reliant on) "lesser beings".

Comment: @AdamV They already rely on them for cooking, cleaning, and other menial jobs, and there's zero issue of being indebted if you order something you *own* to do something for you. Voldemort is, as far as I'm concerned, an exceptional case - he's totally brilliant and that doesn't allow him to see the worth in "lesser" beings. Wizardkind as a whole, on the other hand, seems acutely aware of just how powerful House Elves are. If it were possible somebody would have used it.

Comment: Harry apparated there, not Dobby.

Comment: Except Dobby _didn’t_ do it. He was busy having a knife thrown at him. Harry spun on the spot, Harry concentrated on the goal, Harry Apparated. Ron and Hermione also Apparated there with no house elf, so even if Dobby could Apparate there if he wanted to (and I'm sure he could), Ron would still have had to be Secret Keeper for that to be the answer in this particular case.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist In the very instance under discussion Dobby brought humans along while disapparating from a place with anti-apparition protections.